# How to Map Array of Integer in Hibernate mapping file?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I am developing a web-application in Java and using Hibernate as ORM and **PostgreSQL** Database and have following persistent class:

```
public class SplitterDetail {
    private long splitterID;
    private int locationID;
    private long projectID;
    private int[] ontlist;  
}
```

How can I Map  **SplitterDetail** class particularly **ontlist** attribute in Hibernate Mapping file. Looking for a step by step clearly stated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below example

[Hibernate Configuration example](http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application)